# Replace Name Attribute with Variable - JQUERY

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using a select element to change the search type on a media site (i.e. search by genre, search by artist).

I have created the dropdown and can get the selected option via a variable but now I need to replace the name attribute on the input element with the variable/selected option.  I have seen the below code to change the "value", is there anything like this for changing the name attribute on an input element.

```
$("input[name$='letter']").val("a letter");
```

Answer (score 5):

`.attr('name', 'blah')`