# How can i replace the Dom Elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to Replace the dom element in jquery ?

I tried the replaceWith function but What i want is after the changing in the select box

```
$('select[name="role_id"]').on('change',function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 3){ 
                // I want to replace the role_id name into product_id   

            }
    }
```

Comment: `What i want is afte` - what?

Comment: after change of the select field into the value of 3 i want to change the name from role_id to other-Name_id

Comment: how does your html look like?

Comment: oh, after ... didn't think of that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace Name Attribute with Variable - JQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959660/replace-name-attribute-with-variable-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

[Try .attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)

```
$('select[name="role_id"]').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 3){
        $(this).attr('name', 'product_id');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .attr in Jquery.

```
$('select[name="role_id"]').on('change',function(){
if ($(this).val() == 3){ 
            $(this).attr('name','product_id')

        }
}
```